# Path/File access error (Error 75) whilst opening a file to read

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search for certain keywords in a particular file. but I am getting the afore-mentioned error when I try to open it. does anyone know how to overcome that error.

```js
Function SearchTextFile(strFileName As String, strSearch As String) As Boolean
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim lngLine As Long
    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    f = FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Input As #f
    Do While Not EOF(f)
        lngLine = lngLine + 1
        Line Input #f, strLine
        If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            SearchTextFile = True
            blnFound = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Close #f
    If Not blnFound Then
        SearchTextFile = False
    End If
End Function


Sub Macro1()
    Dim inputString As string: inputString = "mux.h"
    Dim filepath As String: filepath = "C:\Users\310217955\Documents\Source Code\SourceCode\HPLED\Hpled6_2547\test.cpp"
    If SearchTextFile(filepath, inputString) Then
            Debug.Print "Found"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not Found"
        End If 
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs if the  code syntax is wrong or due to not having proper rights to access a program.

Now First part regarding Code Syntax, I have scrutinized and tested your code on sample file and I confirm that Your code syntax is correct and it functions well.
Regarding Second part :
This runtime error 75 usually occurs when you attempt to access a program but you don’t have the rights to access. To resolve this issue, follow these steps below:

1. Click the “Start” button, type “msconfig” in the Search box, and
   then press ENTER.
2. On the “General” tab, click the “Selective
   Startup”, and select “clear the Load Startup Items check box”
3. Click the “Services” tab, select the “Hide All Microsoft Service” at
   bottom, and click “Disable All”, and then click “OK”.
4. After the error disappeared, restart computer, and then set computer to       start normal.
5. Click the “Start” button, type “msconfig” in the Search box,
   and then press ENTER.
6. On the “General” tab, click the “Normal
   Startup” to “load all device drivers and services”, and then click
   “OK”.
7. Restart your computer again.

(Source: www.regmender.com)
Hope it will be able to solve your problem. General points to look into are path is accessable, security setting enable file opening, there is no infection of virus in the system. Also make sure Read-only and Hidden are not checked for files and folders being accessed.  If they are, uncheck both boxes, click on "Apply" then "OK".

HTH

.